# difference between lipschitz domain and domain satisfying the cone condition

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, lipschitz-functions

I've come across two definition and I cant understand the differences between them. Maybe someone can help me..Whats the  difference between a *lipschitz* domain and a domain satisfying the *cone* condition? What are some counter examples?

**Cone condition definition** : $Ω ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the cone condition if there exists a bounded cone with
positive angle that can be moved within the domain to touch each boundary point such that
the cone lies inside the domain.

**Lipschitz domain definition**:$Ω ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ has Lipschitz boundary if there is a finite open cover $\cup^n_{i=0}Ui\supset\bar{\Omega}$

such that for each i, $∂Ω ∩ Ui$ is graph of a Lipschitz continuous function.

Comment: What is the two defenition? We cannot answer since we don't know what you really want to be answered.

Comment: ok I've added the definitions

Comment: Seems that also the slit domain $[-1,1]^2 \setminus (\{0\} \times [0,1])$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

The double brick domain in $\mathbb R^3$ is not Lipschitz but satisfies the cone condition.

It seems from the definition that if two domains satisfy the cone condition then their union will satisfy it as well, which is not true for Lipschitz domains.

Comment: Its is true in saying that all lipschitz domain satisfy the cone condition?